# Kendo UI Diagram - content text values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm using shapeDefaults in constructing the diagram. The content -> text value should refer to the node's name property. For example, if the node object is:

```
var data = [{
            designation: "CEO",
            name: "Mitchell Johnson",
            manages: [{
              designation: "Vice President",
              name: "Smith Cooper",
              manages: [{
                designation: "Director",
                name: "Andrew Walker"
              }, {
                designation: "Director",
                name: "Robert Thompson"
              }]
            }, {
              designation: "Vice President",
              name: "Harris Jones",
              manages: [{
                designation: "Director",
                name: "Edward Collins"
              }, {
                designation: "Director",
                name: "Thomas Wang"
              }]
            }]
           }];
```

Here content -> text should refer to 'name' attribute and display it in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add 'shapeDefaults' to the diagram config:

```
shapeDefaults: 
{
    visual: visualTemplate
},
```

In the function visualTemplate, add your way of marking it up like :

```
function visualTemplate(options) 
{
    var dataviz = kendo.dataviz;
    var g = new dataviz.diagram.Group();
    var dataItem = options.dataItem;

    g.append(new dataviz.diagram.Rectangle(
    {
        width: 210,
        height: 75,
        stroke: 
        {
            width: 0
        },
        fill: dataItem.color
    }));
    g.append(new dataviz.diagram.TextBlock(
    {
        text: dataItem.name,
        x: 5,
        y: 20,
        color: "#fff"
    }));
}
```

if you ever get to know how to center the text, please tell me. I am looking for it :)

you can also look at : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/diagram/index